# Create PDF file from google doc app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have built a google script to create files from a template file and then to update the with data. I do not have any issues making the Google Docs and also updating the files with the data that I want. However, when I create the PDFs from the newly updated documents the PDFs do not have the updated file information.

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('Folder ID')
var FileName = "myFileName"
var newDoc = DriveDocTemp.makeCopy(FileName).getId();
var body = DocumentApp.openById(newDoc).getBody();
body.replaceText('{UpdateText}', "The New Date is 5/11");
var PDFName = "New PDF File name"
var PDFdoc = DriveApp.getFileById(newTsDoc).getAs("application/pdf"); 
var pdf = PDFdoc.setName(PDFName); 
folder.createFile(pdf)
```

When I open up the newly created PDF file it seem that the `{UpdateText}` field is still in the file and it was not updated when I open the PDF File however when I open the google doc file the text was correctly replaced with `The New Date is 5/11`

Comment: Please put `DocumentApp.openById(newDoc).saveAndClose();` after the line of `body.replaceText('{UpdateText}', "The New Date is 5/11");` and test it again. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveandclose)

Comment: @Tanaike I was unaware of the saveAndClose(). That solved it thanks for the tip.